# The minimizing problem over a sequence of shrinking balls

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

Let $B(0,r)\subset \mathbb R^3$ be a ball centered at $0$ with radius $r$. Define 
$$  \mathcal A_r:=\{u\in H_0^1(B(0,r)),\,\,\|u\|_{L^{q+1}}=1\}$$
where $1<q<5$. Hence we know that each $\mathcal A_r$ is weakly closed with respect to $H_0^1$ norm.

Now I am interesting in to see whether I can find a constant $C>0$ such that 
$$ \max_{r>0}\min_{u\in\mathcal A_r}\int_{B(0,r)}|\nabla u|^2\leq C $$

Could this be possible? If no, please provide me a conterexample.

I also put this question in MSE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1132206/the-minimizing-problem-over-a-sequence-of-shrinking-balls), please feel free to ask me to delete it if you feel it is duplicated. Thank you.

---

Update:

It looks to me that if $1+\epsilon<q<5$ will work, but not just $1<q<5$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1132206/the-minimizing-problem-over-a-sequence-of-shrinking-balls

Comment: @WillJagy Yes I also put this link in my post.

Comment: Rescale rescaling you can consider the problem,  $\min\Vert u\Vert_{H^1_0(B(0,1))}$ given that $\Vert u\Vert_{L^{q+1}}=\rho$.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu Can you provide more details please? Thank you! I also update my post as well.

Comment: More details: represent  $v\in H^1_0(B(0,r))$ as $v(x)=u(x/r)$ for $u\in H^1_0(B(0,1))$, and rephrase conveniently the problem only talking of $ H^1_0(B(0,1))$ and $L^{q+1}(B(0,1))$.